# How to turn step function into a linear one?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I've created a step function using Matlab and played it.

While playing, I recorded back the output (using microphone placed near the speaker) and saw that instead of a step function, what actually been recorded back was a linear function.

So, my questions are:

1. Why didn't I record back a step function?
2. What will be a good method to turn the original step function into a linear one, so I will be able to compare them?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you actually did? Maybe the code, or maybe plots of the generated and recorded signals?

Comment: @hbaderts - I attached the plot

Comment: Also, any phisical sytem has a dumping effect on it. That is physics. You are asking the same question as "why if I put my pedal to the top my car did not get instantaneous velocity of 150Km/h". Well, because you cant! Physics!

Comment: You might find this interesting https://xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml

Comment: Can you also include the code? What happens when you try to play it slower, i.e. wait longer before increasing the amplitude? Do you hear the discrete amplitude steps yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to pass a file like

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32000 32000 32000 32000

to a physical speaker it cannot instantaneously jump from the neutral position to the maximum position. It's not physically possible for the speaker to move that fast. And in fact you might break the speaker, so the software will build in protection (you get step functions when microphones saturate out).

But exactly how fast your speaker can move I don't know.